# Babel Transform Runtime issue with Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Good afternoon,

This is the same issue I reported at [webpack's github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4961), but I suspect I might be the one doing something wrong, thus opening a question here.

I'm trying to configure **webpack 2** with **Babel**, and one of the requirements is to transpile built-ins such as `Symbol`.

Despite that now working fine, when I try to use webpack and babel's transform-runtime, I'm unable to use `exports *`.

**Input file** (src/index.js):

```
export * from './secondFile'
```

**secondFile.js:**

```
export let TESTSYMBOL = Symbol('test');

export let TESTSYMBOL2 = Symbol('test2');
```

**webpack.config.js** (only copied the relevant part):

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            // Skip any files outside of `src` directory
            include:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ["es2015", "stage-3"],
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime']
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**script**:

```
"webpack -d --config config/webpack.config.js"
```

**Output file**: [gist](https://gist.github.com/Apidcloud/2b0e6009c4f6f15b272a6dbf1739c6bc)

**Exception**:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined - at Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
```

**Dev Dependencies:**

- "webpack": "2.6.1",
- "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.5",
- "webpack-notifier": "1.5.0"
- "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
- "babel-loader": "7.0.0",
- "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
- "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
- "babel-preset-stage-3": "6.24.1"

**Dependencies:**
 - "babel-runtime": "6.23.0"

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the problem is with the `include`. For some reason, I was unable to use `path.resolve` or `path.join`. The webpack [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition) has such example.

If the webconfig is as follows, it works just fine:

```
 module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: [
                /src/
            ],
            // or exclude: [/node_modules/],
            use: 
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                        presets: ['es2015', 'stage-3']

                    }
                }

        }
    ]
}
```

Either way, now there's a problem with `exports not defined`, which can be solved by setting modules to false in es2015 preset (thanks to Vanuan at Github for that suggestion):

```
presets: [['es2015', { modules: false }], 'stage-3'],
```

Answer (score 0):

For IE or older browsers, I need to use **es-shims** - libraries which ports the ECMAScript specs to legacy JS engines.

These libs below may resolve your problem if added as the first imports on your index.html (or equivalent). Here's one for example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.7/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
```

See this link for every lib you may need:
[ES-Shims](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim#example-of-applying-es-compatability-shims-in-a-browser-project)

Comment: I understand. The internet explorer thing was just an example. The output differs from the one running babel manually (which makes symbol work on browsers such as IE.

Comment: But thanks a lot! It's a handy resource to keep in mind

Comment: No problem. I'll look further to some resolution to your problem. If I find, I'll post here.

Comment: I think I found the error. I'll update with the answer!

Comment: It was a mistake in the webpack configuration as I suspected @Nimrod